# Image thumb disappear when I remove first array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dropzone

I'm trying to make an image drag n drop with react-dropzone, and when I drop a image at dropzone, it is stored in react state, in a files array.

The problem is when i remove an image from array, the thumbs of the remaining items disappear.

Here is a example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jej14g?file=App.tsx

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `handleDeleteImage` method

All you have to do is

- clone the existing array
- revoke the URL at the requested `index`
- remove the element
- update the `files` state

```
 function handleDeleteImage(index: number) {
    const filesArray = [...files];
    URL.revokeObjectURL(filesArray[index].preview);
    filesArray.splice(index, 1);
    setFiles(filesArray);
  }
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pxxyng?file=App.tsx